# Customizing how my object is displayed in the JS console

Tags: javascript, debugging, console.log

I have implemented this immutable Pos object:

```
var Pos = function(x, y) {
    var _x = x;
    var _y = y;
    return {
        x: function() { return _x; },
        y: function() { return _y; },
    };
}
```

Now when I write `new Pos(5, 7)` to the console, it is displayed like this:

```
▶ Object {x: function, y: function} // Chrome
Object { x: Pos/<.x(), y: Pos/<.y() } // Firefox
```

That is not useful at all, as I cannot see the values for `x` and `y`.
I could make a custom function to log `x` and `y`, but that would really not be as good, and I would lose the useful possibility to expand the object and navigate inside (imagine more complex objects, Pos is just one example).

If it was in C#, I would just override ToString(), and then Visual Studio would automatically use it in the debugger to display my object.

In JS however implementing toString doesn't seem to help at all. Is there any way to see my object's `x` and `y` easily in the console?

Comment: chrome is already showing you the x and y values, which are functions. use getters if you want getters; for example:  `get x() { return _x; },` otherwise, there's no link to the private var w/o executing the method, which the console won't do for obvious reasons.

Comment: @dandavis Interesting, I didn't know there were getters in JS. Let me check if this works.

Comment: yeah, a lot of coders overlook them, but they were added in ES5 and now work everywhere (ie8+).

Comment: I'm not sure how to make getters work with my kind of object (I'm a JS newbie). Could you please post some sample code as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get better console behavior in chrome, maybe others, using ES5 getters:

```
function Pos(x, y) {
    return {
        get x() { return x; },
        get y() { return y; },
    };
}
console.log( Pos(1,5) );
```

to avoid possible wasted cpu, chrome won't calc the getter in the console until you click on it, but at least that's all you have to do. Above and beyond that, you'll have to craft your own logger method, or use completely custom objects.

Comment: Ok, getters seem to work in the console, I get `▶ Object {x: (...), y: (...)}`, and then clicking the (...) expands it to show the value. That's not as good as in C#, especially if I have lots of values to view, but it is better than nothing. Thank you.